# Why does only Safari refuse to make button with flex layout vertically align text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.large-item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px;
}

.text-item {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="flex">
  <div class="large-item"></div>
  <span class="text-item">One</span>
  <span class="text-item">Two</span>
</button>
```

This is what Firefox displays:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

This is what desktop Safari displays:

[image: Safari screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @LGSon, this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: I know ..... :)